# Rails 5.2 credentials.yml.enc ERB not parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, erb, twilio-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to setup SMS texting with Twilio. I'm going thru their guide here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-sms-ruby-rails-5-coffee.html but am running into an issue with the ERB in credentials.yml.enc not being parsed for the twilio credentials.

I've tried adding the credentials without using the ERB recommended in the guide, which works, but which would stop me from being able to define these as environment variables.

```
# config/credentials.yml

twilio_account_sid:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "XXXXXXX") %>
twilio_auth_token:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN", "XXXXXXX") %>
twilio_phone_number:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER", "XXXXXXX") %>
```

```
# config/initializers/twilio.rb

Twilio.configure do |config|
  config.account_sid = Rails.application.credentials.twilio_account_sid
  config.auth_token = Rails.application.credentials.twilio_auth_token
end
```

I ran this in the console:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new
  client.messages.create({
    from: Rails.application.credentials.twilio_phone_number,
    to: '+11231234',
    body: 'Hello there! This is a test'
  })
```

I end up getting:

```
URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "XXXXXXX") %>/Messages.json)
```

I'm guessing this is because Rails 5.2's new encrypted credentials.yml file doesn't get processed with ERB. Anyone have a good workaround? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: To edit the credentials and use the .enc file, run `EDITOR=vi rails credentials:edit` and put the keys right in there (instead of using env variables or a credentials.yml file).

Comment: What is the value of `Rails.application.credentials.twilio_phone_number` when outputted with `puts`? Is it `<%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER", "XXXXXXX") %>`?

Comment: Yes ```Rails.application.credentials.twilio_phone_number``` ends up being ```<%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER", "XXXXXXX") %>```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misusing the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file.

Before that feature, people would use environment variables to store secrets (since it would be bad practice to commit them into your code repository). This was a hassle.

So then, Rails 5.2 introduced the encrypted store. The point is that you don't anymore have to manage environment variables, you just commit directly your secrets into your codebase (but encrypted of course).

So either you write directly your secrets into the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file, either you want to keep them in environment variables and then just use an initializer file in `config/initializers/`. Don't do both at the same time.

Comment: It's possible that I'm misusing it. I just started working with 5.2. I guess I thought I could use environment variables to define different values for dev/staging environments that way. How would you suggest doing that if not using environment variables?